# react-bootstrap throws error "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the package off https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

It simply says you must npm install the package, and then has some very ambiguous instructions on browser globals:

```
We provide react-bootstrap.js and react-bootstrap.min.js bundles with all components exported on the window.ReactBootstrap object. These bundles are available on unpkg, as well as in the npm package.

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>

<script>var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;</script>
```

As well as for the CDN they have provided.

```
How and which Bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the simplest way is to include the latest styles from the CDN. A little more information about the benefits of using a CDN can be found here.
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

I downloaded the package in the local react directory, where my public, src, package.json, etc are. Once I try using the components off the package, it gives me the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./~/react-bootstrap/cjs/Container.js
Module parse failed: C:\Users\joemo\Documents\Active\JoeOMGWorks\joeomgworks\node_modules\react-bootstrap\cjs\Container.js Unexpected token (29:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (29:2)
 @ ./src/Components/GlobalHeader.js 17:17-53
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

The message is above my knowledge. There isn't a clear answer on whether it is a webpack configuration I must do, or if I have to download something extra. Looking at Container.js (29:2) is the following:

```
23 const Container = /*#__PURE__*/React.forwardRef(({
24  bsPrefix,
25  fluid,
26  // Need to define the default "as" during prop destructuring to be compatible with styled-components github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3595
27 as: Component = 'div',
28  className,
**29  ...props**
30}, ref) => {
31  const prefix = (0, _ThemeProvider.useBootstrapPrefix)(bsPrefix, 'container');
32  const suffix = typeof fluid === 'string' ? `-${fluid}` : '-fluid';
33  return /*#__PURE__*/(0, _jsxRuntime.jsx)(Component, {
34    ref: ref,
35    ...props,
36    className: (0, _classnames.default)(className, fluid ? `${prefix}${suffix}` : prefix)
37  });
38});
```

What exactly is the appropriate loader and why is it not included in the npm download or why do I need a loader for this npm package? Unfortunately this is the first step to even be able to use this package. Not a good start with this one.